# Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase' only on some domains

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I have developed a Construct 3 game which has a strange behaviour.

On some hosts it works perfectly and it creates and inexedDB and objectStorage without a problem, but on the current host I get the error:

```
Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
```

The strange thing is that this only happens on the current domain. If I use another domain I own there is no such problem.

I also tried implementing the `onupgradeneeded` function but nothing happens. Whenever I try to access the objectStorage I get the error stated above.

Aprart from that error (but as a consequence) I also get

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
```

I really ran out of solutions and I am curios if any of you guys have has encountered this problem before.